# What is the highest resolution external display that can be driven by the Late 2012 13" Retina MacBook Pro

Tags: display, macbook-pro, resolution

The MacBook is configured with 2.5 GHz Intel i5 processor, 8 GB of RMA and the Intel HD Graphics 4000 with 768 MB shared memory.

It's running Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45).

In particular, I'm wondering if it can drive Ultra HD display with a resolution of 3840 × 2160?

Answer (score 11):

If you are talking about the non-Retina version, then the highest it can go is 2560 x 1600 pixels for one display. ([Source (under "Graphics and Video Support")](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP649)).

If you are talking about the Retina version, then it can also go up to 2560 x 1600 pixels, but up to two displays. ([Source (under "Graphics and Video Support")](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP658))

Conclusion: you should still be able to use the display in question, but your Mac will only let your monitor go up to 2560 x 1600.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if some monitors worked well past the "supported" limit, but it's also dicey going out of support as sometimes there are real glitches and errors. Especially if the op is ok tweaking the driver settings on OS X. Well have to see with Mavericks and new displays coming out whether 10.8 gets drivers for monstrous pixel counts as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the official link that says that you can connect a 4k monitor but at 30HZ, and on some setups (e.g. macbook pro retina late 2013) at 60HZ

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht6008

Also, the support article on thunderbolt FAQ is relevant to what monitors can be driven at high resolutions:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3382#11

Answer (score 0):

This program allows to list all supported resolutions and switch to highest one http://specialmeaning.blogspot.com/2016/07/yes-apple-i-did-it.html