# How can I get my 13 inch MBP (A1425) to display 4k?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I just got this monitor, [http://www.amazon.com/Seiki-SE39UY04-39-Inch-Ultra-120Hz/dp/B00DOPGO2G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DOPGO2G)

When I  plug it into my MBP's HDMI port, the highest resolution I can choose on it under the "scaled" option is 1080p. Why is this? I've upgraded OSX to 10.9.3 but it has not helped me at all. Any ideas? I've also tried using a thunderbolt to hdmi adapter but that didn't work either.

Comment: look in about this mac, and what it shows for the monitor

Comment: It shows my retina display and it shows my 4k display as a 1080p display

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the highest resolution external display that can be supported by a late 2012 13in MacBook Pro](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113720/what-is-the-highest-resolution-external-display-that-can-be-supported-by-a-late)

Comment: try holding the Option key when clicking on Scale to see if it comes up with higher resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [Apple Spec Sheet](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp658) for that model:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays, at millions of colors

Looks like that model does not support 4K displays

Answer (score 0):

Holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while clicking on Scaled should show you all the options for that display.

Comment: Looks like this model doesn't support 4k then, it just lists smaller resolutions.

Comment: what is the biggest you see